# KOLite Activity Indicator Configuration

Tags: knockout-2.0, kolite

I am using [KOLite](https://github.com/CodeSeven/KoLite) on a project, and have everything working properly.  The activity indicator works perfectly inside a button or in a small area.

My question is: Is there a way to configure the activity indicator per binding?  For instance, it would be nice to have a large indicator in a div while records are loading, etc.

I hate to use a different indicator in certain places.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The one in kolite hooks into the control you nbind it to. However, you could create your own activity indicator for the page (or region) and wire up the code to turn it on and off in your kolite commands' completed handlers. Its a bit more custom, but there's nothing wrong with that.